# How to calculate the distance between two places using Haversine Formula in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, formula, haversine

I want to calculate the distance between two places using Haversine formula. Actually i am having the latitude and longitude values of two places. Now i want to calculate the distance between that places using Haversine formula.

For Eg:

```
 First Place: 
           "lat" :  12.97159870,
           "lng" : -77.59456270

Second Place:
           "lat" :  9.915996999999999,
           "lng" : -78.1218470
        },
```

Now i want to calculate the distance using **Haversine Formula**.

Please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, you've got search engines, just like the rest of us ... Wikipedia led me here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, seems trivial. Or are you having some specific fundamental problem?

Answer (score 12):

You can use CLLocation class (CoreLocation.framework) method's distanceFromLocation:(CLLocation*)loc;

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];
CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
[locA release]; [locB release];
```

Comment: does it use haversine formula or some other?

Answer (score 6):

iOS provides standard means to calculate the distance between 2 geographic locations - you need to use CLLocation class for that:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocation *loc1 = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:12.97159870 longitude:-77.59456270] autorelease];

CLLocation *loc2 = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 9.915996 longitude:-78.1218470] autorelease];

double distance = [loc1 distanceFromLocation: loc2];
```

You'll also need to add `CoreLocation.framework` to link with your project.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But client wants to be calculate the distance between two places using Haversine Formula. Do you have any idea about how to use Haversine Formula? Thanks.

Comment: @Pugal, if you want to apply Haversine formula yourself check the link "Noon silk" provided.

Comment: @grisleyB the link to js implementation was posted above: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html . I ported it few years ago to obj-c, but I won't be able to find sources now. That should be straightforward anyway

Answer (score 1):

//  Copy library to your project https://github.com/heycarsten/haversine-objc. Then you get distance between two location by using

```
    Haversine *hvs = [[Haversine alloc]initWithLat1:Lati1 lon1:Longi1 lat2:Lati2 lon2:Longi2];
```

// Getting Distance using Math Formula..

```
    double dLat1InRad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(Lati1);
    double dLong1InRad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(Longi1);
    double dLat2InRad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(Lati2);
    double dLong2InRad = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(Longi2);
    double dLongitude = dLong2InRad - dLong1InRad;
    double dLatitude = dLat2InRad - dLat1InRad;
    double a = pow(sin(dLatitude/2.0), 2)+ cos(dLat1InRad) * cos(dLat2InRad) * pow(sin(dLongitude / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2.0 * asin(sqrt(a));
    const double kEarthRadiusKms = 6376.5;
    double dDistance = kEarthRadiusKms * c;
```

Comment: When using Math formula Don't forget to import math.h

Comment: #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)